# Visual Studio 2019: Cannot `import` C++ Standard Library declaration in cpp file without importing it in a separate module (ixx) first

Tags: c++, module, visual-studio-2019, c++20

When attempting to use the C++20 `import` command to load a Standard Library declaration in a .cpp file, a compiler error saying the "header unit" cannot be found is returned.

For example, in a file, say *Main.cpp*, I put

```
import <iostream>;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

The following compiler error results:

`error C7612: could not find header unit for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\iostream'`

However, if I add a module to the project, say *Test.ixx*, as follows

```
export module Test;
import <iostream>;
```

and then import the module `Test` in Main.cpp:

```
import Test;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Then, no problem.  The code builds just fine.

Is this just a case of the C++20 compiler implementations still being worked out?  My impression so far has been that the Standard Library headers should be "importable" unconditionally -- ie without requiring an `import` in a module elsewhere -- but then I've only recently started to experiment with new features in C++20.

Note: I've tried this out with other Standard Library declarations as well, eg `<vector>` etc, with the same results.

Answer (score 7):

There are 3 options to enable to use Standard Library Modules in Visual Studio:
In Project Properties C/C++:

1. C++ Language Standard: Preview - Features From the Latest C++ Working Draft /std:c++latest
2. Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules: Yes (/experimental:module)
3. Scan Sources For Module Dependencies: Yes

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.8

Answer (score 2):

Importing the stl is not specified in C++20, but VS allows this by doing

```
import std.core;
```

Snippet from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160

> Although not specified by the C++20 standard, Microsoft enables its implementation of the C++ Standard Library to be imported as modules. By importing the C++ Standard Library as modules rather than #including it through header files, you can potentially speed up compilation times depending on the size of your project. The library is componentized into the following modules:

> std.regex provides the content of header <regex> 
> std.filesystem provides the content of header <filesystem> 
> std.memory provides the content of header <memory> 
> std.threading provides the contents of headers <atomic>, <condition_variable>, <future>, <mutex>, <shared_mutex>, and <thread> 
> std.core provides everything else in the C++ Standard Library 
> To consume these modules, just add an import declaration to the top of the source code file.

Comment: That now says: "As of Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1, C++20 standard modules are fully 
implemented in the Microsoft C++ compiler.  Before it was specified by the C++20 standard, Microsoft had experimental support for modules. The compiler also supported importing prebuilt Standard Library modules, described below. Starting with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5, importing the Standard Library as a module is both standardized and fully implemented in the Microsoft C++ compiler. "

But I'm still getting the issue in VS Version 17.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [Walkthrough: Import STL libraries as header units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-import-stl-header-units?view=msvc-160) now there are two ways to make standard headers importable:

1. Enable build system scan for imported header files. It can be enabled by "Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Scan Sources for Module Dependencies" which has following description: "Makes the build scan all c++ sources, not just module interface and header unit sources, for module and header units dependencies". As you can see from the description, without this option only module interface and header unit sources are scanned for the dependencies. Be aware that scanning all sources in large projects can take a long time. So it is preferrable to use second way.
2. Make another static library project that build all header units you want to use and reference this library in your original project. For example, this static library can contain single cpp file that contains only `import`s of all needed header units and this library can use "Scan Sources for Module Dependencies" (from p.1) without affecting build time of original project.