# VS2022 preview, error C7612: could not find header unit for…” on importing a standard header (for example “import <vector>;”

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022

From my limited understanding the following should compile,

```
import <concepts>;
```

I found the following related bug on MS Developer Community with the comment,

[severity:It bothers me. A fix would be nice]
I’m getting “error C7612: could not find header unit for…” on importing a standard header (for example “import ;” ) in any cpp-file whenever there is no correspondig import in an ixx-file. There is no step for vector in “1>Scanning sources for module dependencies…” unless it is mentioned in an ixx-file.

I could not identify the bug, and it is closed as not a bug. This seems to be pertaining to an earlier compiler. I'm using VS2022 preview.

I tried to work with the advanced compiler options on VS2022 as suggested by Olga and I could not find a way to use the import directive for a standard header file.

The current header units support is more like precompiled headers support and require some user action to tell project system which header units to build. Please refer to Project System section in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/standard-c20-modules-support-with-msvc-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-8/ for the recommended way of doing this.

You can also set “Scan All Sources for Module Dependencies” to “Yes” in C/C++ Advanced page of Project (of File) Properties UI.
It will make project system automatically build all imports. but will build and intellisense will be slower.

The reason I am jumping to this as this is an incredibly important feature I have been waiting on and I need to see it work so I could be reasonably confident with forward development using the mechanism. This also fails on GCC.

Now I understand that it requires great compiler tool support. It reminds me of having to compile boost, this is going back some time. There seems to be a flavor of PCH involved with this too.

I hope there is a simple way in order to support importing of standard header files.

Emily

Comment: Using the mentioned close bug as a guide, I put import <concepts>; et al into the header file, (.h) compiled it as an export header. I needed to again import <inostream>; in the cpp file too and it worked. It seems a little counter-intuitive that one cannot place the import directive just directly in the implementation file. I did not even need to restate the import directives in the .cpp for all the but <iostream>, and this may be the nature of the <iostream> header file. The solution was very simple yet still somewhat counter intuitive to me.

Comment: I wouldn't have too high expectations to something which has "preview" in its product label (with the only exception of preview tools)... ;-)

Comment: Note that standard library modules aren't standardised yet so I wouldn't rely on them and certainly wouldn't expect any code using them to be cross platform. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-160 for what Microsoft have implemented. I think you need `import std.core`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006729/visual-studio-2019-cannot-import-c-standard-library-declaration-in-cpp-file/69007041#69007041

Comment: See also https://amp.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/l3elnu/current_status_of_the_standard_library_modules/

Comment: if I say import gcc.core; I get, "Error C1011 cannot locate standard module interface. Did you install the library part of the C++ modules feature in VS setup?" I have to install something separately? Where would it be?

Comment: Yes "C++ modules for v142 build tools" looks like a likely suspect to install

Comment: I cannot find that in the installer. BTW using v143 if that matters.

Comment: I think "v142" was a typo in the preview 3 installer, its correctly labelled as "v143" in the latest preview and is [definitely there for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43oin.png) (and not installed by default)

Comment: There is no `gcc.core` ... was that a typo?

Comment: Installed the core and still get the error.

Comment: Yes, it was a bypo, (brain typo). Thank you for your input, I liked what Bjane said of this... "Just as Bjarne said in our AMA panel at the betterCode() C++ event yesterday: he wants to just import std; and be done, and so do I."

Comment: I installed by modifying the installation, "C++ modules for v143 build tools" a number of times. I cannot get it to work. When I go back to the installer, it indicates that it is not installed. Experimental feature.

Comment: Found https://vsf-prod.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/content/problem/1505062/vs-2022-preview-31-cannot-find-standard-module-int.html tried enabling Properties > C/C++ > Language > Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules. and now it compiles. This switch has to be set on Yes (/experimental:module).